# How can I dynamically construct a textbox object reference?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I asked a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594041/how-can-i-programmatically-construct-the-object-reference) and now I need to do the same thing again but this time using VBA in Excel 2010.

Essentially I have numerous text boxes with generic names (i.e. textbox1,textbox2 etc). How can I programically construct the object reference so that I can create a loop?

**EDIT:**
It is a regular textbox on a worksheet. When I start a sub for this worksheet I can reference the textboxes with the following line:

```
TextBox1.LinkedCell = "B2"
```

Comment: What type of textboxes (forms/activeX) and are they on a worksheet or a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your after:

```
Dim oleObj As OLEObject
'Dim oleTxtBox As TextBox

For Each oleObj In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    If oleObj.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
        If Mid(oleObj.progID, 1, 14) = "Forms.TextBox." Then
            Set oleTxtBox = oleObj.Object
            oleTxtBox.PasswordChar = "*"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Just using `PasswordChar` as an example field from the `TextBox` object, but it wouldn't actually left me `Dim` as a `TextBox`

Comment: It worked thank you. I had to change Set oleTxtBox = oleObj.Object to Set oleTxtBox = oleObj just fyi.